# Can't remove the shadow below app bar

Tags: android, appbar, android-appbarlayout

Can't remove the shadow below app bar. There are some tips, but none can solve.

Edit appbar style elevation:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Set de appTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Set programatically elevation:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    toolbar.setElevation(0);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterMods(this));

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I solve the problem taking out the widget.AppBarLayout and using only widget.Toolbar and use elevation on Toolbar to place over the view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        <!-- Complete circle of touch response -->
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:theme="@style/MainAppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for removing the shadow use this to your app theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

if you're using the support library you must call it to that like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: The Theme.Holo fails compilation. Using the other points not work yet. I tried open a new base project on android studio and apply this changes. My build min target is 21.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6` - at - `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`